# How to do shutdown with apps quitting and not crashing?

Tags: google-chrome

How to do shutdown with apps quitting and not crashing?

I use chrome and on restart it asks to restore tabs, but i have set to open where i left off, but on shutdown they are killed so they crash and ask to restore.

I need so they quit, exit and chrome comes back where i left off, as i have set in chrome settings.

Comment: Which of the several possible ways are you shutting down your system?

Comment: for gnome `gnome-session-quit --power-off` according to manpage